# linux: spidev is not shown in /dev

Tags: linux, spi, device-tree

I did the following steps in order to use spidev in Linux- kernel 3.14.28 compiled on arm imx6Q (SMARC board, by Yocto-Project):

1. In kernel configuration, I enabled SPIDEV: `CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV=y`.
2. In device tree, I added the following lines:

```
&smarc_spi0 {
   spidev@1 {
      #address-cells = <1>;
      #size-cells = <1>;
      compatible = "linux, spidev";
      spi-max-frequency = <20000000>;
      reg = <1>;   
   };
};
```

I compiled my Linux successfully, and still can't see `/dev/spidev0.1` appear in /dev folder.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I found out the problem: compatible string wasn't accurate..
I had extra space between "linux," and "spidev"..
The appropriate way is: 
compatible = "linux,spidev";